# Javascript Customiser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a Javascript customiser form using Wordpress and woo-commerce. The product to customise is a wristband. I have created my form and it is all in place, I don't need help with Wordpress or woo-commerce.

My form will work in the same way as it does on this site: http://ukwristbands.com/. There are various options the customer needs to select/ go through and they should be able to see what the configured product will look like.

I have managed to get the fonts to display on the wristband as well as the different font sizes and the custom printed text however I need to display an icon on the product as well as the text and the position of the logo will change depending on which option the user selects.

My form is generated using woo-commerce and in my javascript I am using the ID or class of the select dropdown to target the relevant fields onChange.

Here is my JS:

```
//wristband colour & font selectors
var selectedScheme = 'Aqua';
$('#pa_colour').change(function(){
    $('#band-viewer').removeClass(selectedScheme).addClass($('#pa_colour option:selected').attr('class'));
    selectedScheme = $('#pa_colour option:selected').attr('class');

});
var selectedType = 'Georgia';
$('#pa_typeface').change(function(){
    $('#band-viewer').removeClass(selectedType).addClass($('#pa_typeface option:selected').attr('class'));
    selectedType = $('#pa_typeface option:selected').attr('class');
});
var selectedFontSize = 'Small';
$('#pa_font-size').change(function(){
    $('#band-viewer').removeClass(selectedFontSize).addClass($('#pa_font-size option:selected').attr('class'));
    selectedFontSize = $('#pa_font-size option:selected').attr('class');
});
```

Every time the selection changes the JS adds selected options class to the div with an ID of band-viewer and this triggers my CSS to show the change.

Here is the dropdown that is generated by woo-commerce:

```
<select id="pa_font-size" name="attribute_pa_font-size" class="hasCustomSelect" style="-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 599px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 74px; font-size: 37px;">
  <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
  <option value="small" selected="selected" class="small     active">Small</option>
  <option value="medium" class="medium active">Medium</option>
  <option value="large" class="large active">Large</option>
</select>
```

I want to make sure that the select dropdowns work with each other and show the configured product with all the options the user selected so they can see what their wristband would look like.

Comment: no idea what is the aim here or if there is a issue to be solved

Comment: I have some select dropdowns in form and when the user selects an option from one or more of them the change is displayed on screen so they can see what their finished product would look like.

Comment: re-reading your q it appears you want to add a image to some div somewhere. 1st step would be to mock up the html to display the image where ever you want it. You can either create empty divs where  you want the images to appear or control position by class. use jQuery html if you want to populate a div with code or .attr if you want to change class etc.